# Initiates repeatedly $interval in angularjs on state change

Tags: angularjs, timer, setinterval, intervals

I am building a time-tracker using $interval. When I change state/route to another page and come back to time-tracker page it initiates another interval and so speeds up the timer. I did a search and found I need to cancel interval on state change like this;

```
 $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {$interval.cancel(timer); });
```

But I don't want to stop interval because it is stopping the timer as well. I want to run this in the background, and so need to avoid initiating more intervals on state changes back and forth.

Please suggest any alternative solution.

Comment: Put that in a service, which is a singleton, and will thus be shared by all instances of your controller(s).

Comment: I put all in service but problem remains same, and also having scope sharing issue. please will you describe little brief how I can implement service with use of scope.